# Add count of contained divs within each div via jQuery

Tags: jquery

This seems like it should work but for some reason it isn't. Can anyone help?

I am trying to add the count of children divs to the "booklist" divs on this page: http://216.172.167.18/~julia/books/

I have this jQuery running:

```
$('.booklist').addClass(function() {
        return $(this).children('div').length;
    });
```

Thanks for your help!
Michelle

Comment: doesn't the class need to be a string ?

Comment: Where do you want that count to appear? And yes, you need to coerce the return value to a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Length is a number, it needs to be a string.

```
$('.booklist').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).children('div').length.toString();
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! Works perfectly. You were so quick I can't even mark this as 'accepted' yet. :)

Comment: also some browsers have problems with class names starting with a number

Comment: Yes, I changed it to return 'num_'+$(this).children('div').length.toString();

Answer (score 1):

you better use each to get to your expected behaviour.
the `.addClass()` takes a string.

work around it trough the `.each();`

```
$('.booklist').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).children('div').length.toString());
});
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/jNks3/1/

*EDIT* keep in mind that the .addClass() function takes a function or a string... not an integer. so a mere .toString() fixes that.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. :( Thanks for looking though.

Comment: how so it didn't work? i get it you use the above solution which is just fine ... but this one has to work as well, doen't the demo on jsFiddle show it working?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it doesn't seem to be working on jsFiddle? (I am certainly not a jsFiddle expert so totally possible <g>) I'm looking for something like <div class="booklist 3"> to show up and I don't see that happening.

Comment: you were totally right, i actually ran in the same problem you did. giving an integer directly into the addClass is not working. needs to be a string.

Comment: Thanks! Learning more all the time :)